# Wide Format Summary in tidyverse

Tags: r, aggregate, tidyverse, summary, summarize

Hi I have a dataframe in wide format that is grouped by `Site`. Each column represents the abundance a different species(85 total). I am trying to summarize the dataframe to calculate the total number of individuals regardless of species in my data.

```
df.totals<- df %>% group_by(Site) %>% summarize (total = sum(6:91))
```

Comment: Is it a rowwise sum or sum of all the columns within the `Site`

Comment: A small example data/expected output would be helpful if you don't mind  (to avoid any confusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `gather` to 'long' format and then do the `sum`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   select(Site, 6:91) %>%
   rownames_to_column("rn") %>% 
   gather(key, val, - Site, -rn) %>% 
   group_by(Site, rn) %>% 
   summarise(total  = sum(val))
```

---

or another option without `gather`ing would be

```
df %>% 
   select(Site, 6:91) %>% 
   transmute(vs, Sum = reduce(.[2:ncol(.)], `+`)) %>%
   group_by(Site) %>% 
   summarise(Sum = sum(Sum))
```

Using a reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
mtcars %>% 
   select(vs, 4:6) %>% 
   transmute(vs, Sum = reduce(.[2:ncol(.)], `+`)) %>% 
   group_by(vs) %>% 
   summarise(Sum = sum(Sum))
```